# ORACLE: Changing the grouping of a data to be based on month breakdowns

Tags: oracle, select, group-by, count

To keep this short and to the point, I am looking at modifying the grouping for this SQL query to go from `NAME` to `Month/yy`

Here is a example of the script, and screenshots of the output file

This is what I am trying to accomplish.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

SQL SCRIPT:

```
SELECT A.NAME
     COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(A.INVDATE,'MM') = '10' THEN A.ORDER_NO ELSE NULL END)) AS OCT11_ORDERS
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(A.INVDATE,'MM') = '10' THEN A.ORDER_NO ELSE NULL END) AS OCT11_LINES
     , COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(A.INVDATE,'MM') = '10' THEN A.INVOICE_NO ELSE NULL END)) AS OCT11_INV_COUNT
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(A.INVDATE,'MM') = '10' THEN A.INVOICE_NO ELSE NULL END) AS OCT11_INV_LINES
-- NOV 11 
     , COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(A.INVDATE,'MM') = '11' THEN A.ORDER_NO ELSE NULL END)) AS NOV11_ORDERS
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(A.INVDATE,'MM') = '11' THEN A.ORDER_NO ELSE NULL END) AS NOV11_LINES
     , COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(A.INVDATE,'MM') = '11' THEN A.INVOICE_NO ELSE NULL END)) AS NOV11_INV_COUNT
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(A.INVDATE,'MM') = '11' THEN A.INVOICE_NO ELSE NULL END) AS NOV11_INV_LINES
-- DEC 11     
     , COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(A.INVDATE,'MM') = '12' THEN A.ORDER_NO ELSE NULL END)) AS DEC11_ORDERS
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(A.INVDATE,'MM') = '12' THEN A.ORDER_NO ELSE NULL END) AS DEC11_LINES
     , COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(A.INVDATE,'MM') = '12' THEN A.INVOICE_NO ELSE NULL END)) AS DEC11_INV_COUNT
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(A.INVDATE,'MM') = '12' THEN A.INVOICE_NO ELSE NULL END) AS DEC11_INV_LINES

FROM test.test1 A 
WHERE TO_DATE(A.INVDATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-OCT-11') AND TO_DATE('30-SEP-12')
AND COMPANY = '30'
AND CUST_GRP IN ('3','4')
GROUP BY A.NAME
```

**OUTPUT FILE**: [image: Current Output file]

**DESIRED OUTPUT** [image: Ideal Output format]

For the desired output, all of the columns should be `counts`

Thanks!

Comment: There was too little information in the question anyway about the base table for anyone to come up with any answer. Glad you figured it out yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, 
had to `group by trucn(invdate,'mm')` and `count` the separate columns

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(inv.invdate,'MM'),'MON-RR') "Month",
         COUNT(DISTINCT(inv.order_no)) "Orders",
         COUNT(inv.order_no) "Order Lines",
         COUNT(DISTINCT(inv.invoice_no)) "Invoices",
         COUNT(inv.invoice_no) "Invoice Lines",
         COUNT(DISTINCT(inv.name)) "Companies"
FROM test.test1 inv
GROUP BY TRUNC(inv.invdate,'MM')
```

[image: Data output for query]